# SWIFT/CloudKit - Updating a record and saving it back to container

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I'm having a problem updating CloudKit records. What I want to achieve is the ability to allow users to vote for a book by clicking a tableview row.
This tableview is currently filled using records from Cloud data.
I'm stuck when I want to retrieve a record (ie. the selected tableview row), and increase its voteCount column by 1, then save it back to the cloud and reload the data in the tableview.

Currently I am retrieving records by:

```
    booksIncludedInVote = []
    let cloudContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicDatabase =CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase

    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Book", predicate: predicate)
    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    queryOperation.desiredKeys = ["name", "author", "image", "description", "voteCount"]
    queryOperation.queuePriority = .VeryHigh
    queryOperation.resultsLimit = 50
    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record:CKRecord!) -> Void in
    if let restaurantRecord = record {
      self.booksIncludedInVote.append(restaurantRecord)
    }
```

Can you help me update a particular record and then send it back up to the cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would also need code like this:

```
    operation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in
            self.tableView.ReloadData()
        }
    publicDatabase.addOperation(operation)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
     var record = self.booksIncludedInVote[indexPath.row]
     // now increment the voteCount value in that record and save it using 
     publicDatabase.saveRecord(theRecord, completionHandler: { record, error in
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Edwin - I've updated my code to now fetch and then setObject of the current record. However I get a "WRITE operation not permitted" error. Do you know how to get round this?

Comment: That could be multiple things. In the CloudKit dashboard you can set permissions for each recordType you have. There is a matrix where you can set 9 different rights. create, read, write against world, authenticated, creator. By default someone can only change it's own records. You probably have to change that to authenticated.

Comment: Excellent - thank you Edwin, together both your answers helped to allow me to update records.

Comment: @EdwinVermeer - Could you suggest an approach to a similar issue using an Action View tied to a button, instead of using a cell in a table?

Comment: Do you mean a UIActionSheet? Then you will use the didDisMissWithButtonIndex function and use the buttonIndex instead of the indexPath.row for getting the correct record.